# Pointers Arrays and Read Only Memory in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, immutability

I am learning the C programming language and am running into difficulties in understanding the minute differences between pointers, arrays and read only memory. I am working with the following example:

```
char *myCards = "JQK";
```

From what I understand what this line of code accomplishes is it creates a null terminated string of characters in a read only section of memory that is accessible via the char pointer `myCards`. This means that I am able to compile the following but would receive an error due to the immutability of the string:

```
*myCards = 'A';
```

I am trying to achieve a similar functionality using an array of ints; however, I am not at all certain on how to create this array and place it in a read only section of memory if at all possible.

I know that I can use the `const` keyword and create an array as follows:

```
const int myInts[] = {3, 6, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2};
```

However, I am able to do the following, directly after this array initialization:

```
printf("First element of array: %i\n", myInts[0]);    
int *myIntsPtr = myInts;
*myIntsPtr = 15;
printf("First element of array: %i\n", myInts[0]);
```

I was able to alter the first element of the array by creating a pointer to it, implying that this array was never placed into read only memory.

Basically I am stuck on trying to figure out how I am able to declare this int array so that it is in read only memory similar to `"JQK"`. Any insight is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: That a string literal is formally not const is a legacy from the old days. It should be.

Comment: You `int *` initialization will declare only `3` as read-only not all elements of array .But is not correct way either.

Comment: Boost up your compiler warning levels. Modifying a `const` array's elements through a non-`const` pointer is simply undefined behavior; literally **anything** might happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, first to understand this, it's important to know that `const` in C doesn't have to do anything with read-only memory. For C, there is no such thing as sections. `const` is merely a contract, it's expressing the intention that something is indeed constant. This means a compiler/linker *can* place data in a read-only section because the programmer assured it won't change. It doesn't *have* to, though.

Second, a string literal translates to a constant array of `char`s with `0` implicitly appended. See Peter Schneider's comment here: it is not *formally* const (so the compiler won't warn you when you take a non-const pointer to it), but it *should* be.

Combining this, the following code segfaults on my system with gcc on Linux amd64, because `gcc` indeed places the array in a read-only section:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int myInts[] = {3, 6, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2};

int main(void)
{
    printf("First element of array: %i\n", myInts[0]);    
    int *myIntsPtr = myInts;
    *myIntsPtr = *(myIntsPtr + 1);
    printf("First element of array: %i\n", myInts[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Note there is also a compiler warning in the line where you take a non-const pointer to the const array.

Btw, the same code will work if you declare the array inside your function with `gcc`, that's because then, the array itself is created on the stack. Still you get the warning, the code is still wrong. It's a *technical detail* of how C is implemented here. The difference to a string literal is that it is an anonymous object (the char array doesn't have an identifier) and has static storage duration in any case.

---

**edit** to explain what a string literal does: The following codes are equivalent:

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *foo = "bar";
}
```

and

```
const char ihavenoname_1[] = {'b', 'a', 'r', 0};

int main(void)
{
    const char *foo = ihavenoname_1;
}
```

---

So, short story, if you want `gcc` to put data in a read-only section, declare it `const` with static storage duration (outside of a function). Other compilers might behave differently.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Would you happen to have a quick explanation or reference as to why my attempt at declaring an int array as follows is wrong: `int *myInts = {3, 6, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2};`. I'm almost there with my understanding but am missing something.

Comment: @AdamBak it's because nobody specified a similar "shorthand" (like a string literal is doing for a `char` array) for declaring an anonymous `int` array in C.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with Felix Palmen. An array within a function is stored on the stack, even if it is const, and you can modify it with the appropriate cast. Here is what I've got with MS-VC++ (ebp is the stack pointer):

```
const int test [ 5 ] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
00309598  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],0 
0030959F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],1 
003095A6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],2 
003095AD  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],3 
003095B4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],4 
( ( int* ) test ) [ 1 ] = 0;
003095BB  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],0
```

Now, defining the array within the function, but as `static const` this time, or defining it as a `const` global variable... We have the same result for both tests: the array is now in the data segment (usage of an address rather than ebp) but can still be modified:

```
static const int test [ 5 ] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
( ( int* ) test ) [ 1 ] = 0;
01449598  mov         dword ptr [test+4 (145ECACh)],0
```

With gcc you will have data in a read-only memory, but as Felix said, it is not garanteed: If you use MS-VC, for instance, you can still modify it.

Comment: Interesting! While I generally dislike MSVC, there's nothing wrong here because writing to an object that was initially *defined* `const` is *undefined behavior* anyways. So the compiler is of course free to do exactly what the programmer probably expected ...