# Defining a dynamic, read-only array in C

Tags: c, dynamic, allocation

How do I define a dynamic read-only integer array in C?

I know that we can allocate static read-only array by using the qualifiers, 'const' and 'static'. But how to do the same in the case of a dynamic array?

Comment: The same: `const int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(*arr));`, but this doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense. You would need to write data into your array at some point. However, you can define a variable that points to the data without allowing modification.

Comment: I think the point you are missing is you fill the array as a read-write array and then pass as `const` to any required function to prevent modification (reading a bit between the lines here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any standard way to *define* dynamically allocated memory as `const`. There wouldn't be much point since you cannot use initialisation for dynamically allocated memory other than `calloc` to initialise it to zero. C simply doesn't have any standard library functions for initialising the memory to anything else. It requires you to use assignment instead, which would never work with `const`.

You can declare a pointer to dynamically allocated memory as `const`, but if you do this, users are permitted (as far as the language standard is concerned) to cast away the `const` and modify the data anyway.

In theory that might not be good enough, but in practice it is. Code which casts away `const` to modify data, especially in ways not clear to the caller, is very uncommon.

Comment: "*users are permitted (as far as the language standard is concerned) to cast away the `const`*", well, doing so still would invoke undefined behaviour, wouldn't it?

Comment: @alk: It is not undefined if the pointer to the const-qualified type originally came from a pointer to a non-const-qualified type. You are always allowed to convert a pointer back to its original type and use it. So you can get something from `malloc`, initialize it, and then pass a pointer to a const-qualified type to other routines, but they may legally cast it back.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Edited to hopefully no longer imply that such a function couldn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `const` qualifier to point to an already created non `const` array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *alloc(int n)
{
    int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(*arr));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int *arr = alloc(5);

    arr[3] = 5; /* error */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: as hvd rightly said, the 'arr' can still be modified by declaring another pointer, say *ptr, to it: *ptr = arr; and *ptr = 64;

Comment: Well ... the compiler must tell you something if you do that: `assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type`

Comment: yup, the compiler gives a warning message only and allows me to go ahead and make changes to the arr, betraying the nature of 'read-only' as was required

Comment: Of course is not an error but a warning, `const` doesn't mean _read only_ in C, but you already know that before asking the question isn't it?

Comment: yes of course! I know const doesn't mean read only in C. That's the reason I  asked the question so as to know if there is any other way to do it. In the case of a variable, we can use const static together to make the variable read only in C. I don't know how to do the same for a dynamic array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AbhinayB: "*we can use const static together to make the variable read only*" are you sure? I'd say no. Also `static` is completely unrelated to any constantness (in C):

Comment: We can use them together, alk. Please read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056598/pointers-arrays-and-read-only-memory-in-c. Felix Palman clearly says, "So, short story, if you want gcc to put data in a read-only section, declare it const with static storage duration (outside of a function). Other compilers might behave differently."

Comment: @AbhinayB:  The closest you can  get to real read-only arrays in C is using string literals, and even their constantness is not backed by the C Standard.

Comment: @AbhinayB: Sure you can use `static`  along  with `const`, but using `static` does not change anything regarding the constantness. If GCC does this, it's GCC's specifc behaviour to do so. It is *not backed by the C Standard*.

Comment: @AbhinayB: Also if you closely look at  Felix' code here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33056752/694576) you'll notice that there is *no* `static` declaration involved.

Comment: @alk: Thx for pointing out that little detail. I understand that now! So the GCC doesn't have a similar behaviour in the case of a dynamic array while it does have a way for a single variable. Thx once again!